# Can one find out which MySQL-queries were slow?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I use the PHP function `mysql_stat()` to obtain information about my MySQL database.

There is an entry `Slow queries`, which in my case is 94 (of 301729 queries). Is there a log-file that contains more information about the queries? (time, execution time, the query itself,...)?

14 Hours ago I set up a new server, with 4 times more RAM,... but still I have 0.031154% slow queries, which is basically the same as before, I think that’s very high. I really like to find out, which are the slow queries, and how to optimize them. What is an acceptable ratio of slow queries?

Comment: Also depends on what the value of long_query_time is.  I've seen it set to '2', which may be fine for OLTP, but is not great for OLAP.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable log-slow-queries in my.cnf. That writes the slow queries to a log.

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

I think you should never have queries slower than .2 seconds if the user needs to wait. When executing crons where no users are involved, it does not matter that much. But if you use the same database / table, the query of the cron can slow down the normal query (locking / i/o).

You can optimize your databse by setting the right indexes, and use EXPLAIN to try different queries.